# allow access to html page only to logged in users

Tags: node.js

I have `app.html` in a public folder which is serving static files to express.

I have used code from [here](https://scotch.io/tutorials/easy-node-authentication-setup-and-local).

But instead of `profile.ejs` from views folder(as per the code in link), I want to serve `app.html` from inside of public folder.

```
  app.get('/app.html', isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
        res.render('app.html'/*, {
            user : req.user // get the user out of session and pass to template
        }*/);
        
        console.log("APP.HTML");
        
    });


function isLoggedIn(req, res, next) {

    // if user is authenticated in the session, carry on 
    if (req.isAuthenticated())
        return next();

    // if they aren't redirect them to the home page
    res.redirect('/');
}
```

But it does not restrict the access to `loggedIn` users and I am able to access it directly after logging out as well.

What could be wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is most likely that you have `express.static()` *before* your `app.get()` line. The static middleware checks if the file exists and sends it if it does. So you need to put that `app.get()` *before* your `express.static()` middleware.

Comment: Worked. Thanks a ton .